# Close UIButton Flicker animation

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I want to close `UIButton` Flicker animation ，I try to use:

```
button.highlighted = NO;
[button setHighlighted:NO];
```

(But has not close `UIButton` flicker animation，No response..)

I try another:

```
[button setEnabled:NO];
```

(Button flicker close，but my button turn white color.)

Please give me some advice ,thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Either of this as per need-

1. This will disable button -

   ```
   button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
   ```
2. In xib file - you can uncheck "highlight adjusts image"

Answer (score 0):

Try showsTouchWhenHighlighted found in the class reference of UIButton